# Other methods on class based views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I currently have a class based view with `get()`, `post()` and `delete()` methods for the following URL:
`/property/<str:property_uuid>`
This works fine and is great.

However, I now want URLs such as `/property/<str:property_uuid>/publish` and `/property/<str:property_uuid>/publish` to make my API easier to use.  These will be GET methods.

I was hoping to have corresponding `publish()` and `unpublish()` functions and put these within my class.  However, I'm not sure how to do this or if this is even posible with class based views?  Would I have to go back to function based views with all my functions defined in a "property.py" file for ease of reference and then include this in my urls.py file?

Comment: Please add your view to the question.

Comment: What base views are you extending? Have a look at https://ccbv.co.uk/ if you have not already but essentially you'd need to point all the urls.py entries to the same class then overload the dispatch method to check the request object in order to determine which url is called. If the 1st you can just super it, otherwise call a new publish() method that handles things. Alternatively add kwargs into your urls.py entry and use self.kwargs within the dispatch method as a hint of which url was being called